# How to use SQL if -then -else statement to create/derive a new column

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, calculated-columns, qlikview

how should the script be like if I want a column 'Before 10am' to be 1 if the column 'Time' is <=10:00:00, else it will be 0? Thanks.

Comment: Is this to be a computed column as part of the table definition or just a new column in a `SELECT` statement? Also, which database system are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It is to be a new column in the table. Qlikview. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
LOAD
if( time#([Time], 'hh:mm:ss') < time#('10:00:00', 'hh:mm:ss'), 'Before 10am') as TimeBefore10am
...
FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` exchange of `if statement` in your select:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN Time <='10:00:00' Then 1 ELSE 0 END AS Before10am
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: this not SQL syntax not QlikView

Comment: Thanks for your comment,it seems you know many things more than me,but it is `SQL` syntax if you don't know.